# Pricing a (general) callable floating rate note

Tags: fixed-income, pricing, floating-rate, callable-bonds

I have a question generalizing this situation: [Pricing Callable Floating Rate Note](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14612/pricing-callable-floating-rate-note).

I want to price a callable floating rate note, where the coupon can also be capped and the reference index can be more complex than just the riskless interest rate for discounting (e.g. a spread between the riskless rate for 3 months and 12 months). In this situation I don't think is accurate to ignore the stochasticity of the interest rate.
The company I am working for started pricing callable bonds using trinomial tree approaches (which is of course reasonable). They want to stick with them also in the floating situation as they are afraid of the high computational costs of Monte Carlo simulations. But now I am struggling to deal with the path dependency in the trinomial tree. Is there any literature on pricing path dependent interest rate products with trinomial trees? The only thing in this direction I found are the ideas in "EFFICIENTPROCEDURES FOR VALUING EUROPEAN AND AMERICANPATH-DEPENDENT OPTIONS" from Hull and White. Still, I am not sure if this computationally doable for an finance industry software.

So, to sum up: does make more sense to apply a path-dependent tree scheme or another tool? Thank you in advance for all insights!